# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, syntax-error, magento2

Only at the checkout and on individual product pages I am getting the following error in the console log:

```
VM35594:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at run (layout.min.js:9)
    at app.min.js:1
    at main.min.js:2
    at Object.execCb (require.min.js:112)
    at Module.check (require.min.js:56)
    at Module.<anonymous> (require.min.js:72)
    at require.min.js:11
    at require.min.js:74
    at each (require.min.js:3)
```

I am using a one page checkout extension, but when I disable that the error still shows. I thought it might had something to do with the reviews on the product page (as I moved the reviews out of the tabs), but undoing that change didn't fix the error on the product pages.

Comment: My best bet is that you are passing `undefined` to `JSON.parse`

Comment: I guess that "checkout" is a POST request to a page where you will start the checkout of an order right? Did you inspect the JSON of that HTTP POST Request? I will start from here just to see what you are sending is what you can managed in the checkout page.

Comment: Open developer tools console and see at the network tab the response of your script. You may not return a proper json.

Comment: Could you place a debugger in your javascript and post the value of your JSON string before it gets passed to `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Hi Howli, have any of our answers helped you? If so, please accept an answer. Otherwise, I'd be happy to help further with more details.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Try this in the console:

```
JSON.parse(undefined)
```

Here is what you will get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6
```

In other words, your app is attempting to parse `undefined`, which is not valid JSON.

There are two common causes for this. The first is that you may be referencing a non-existent property (or even a non-existent variable if not in strict mode).

```
window.foobar = '{"some":"data"}';
JSON.parse(window.foobarn)  // oops, misspelled!
```

The second common cause is failure to receive the JSON in the first place, which could be caused by client side scripts that ignore errors and send a request when they shouldn't.

Make sure both your server-side and client-side scripts are running in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and lint them using [ESLint](https://eslint.org/). This will give you pretty good confidence that there are no typos.

Comment: For me, I had encoded Emoji was invalidating the JSON being decoded.  There was a value in a string in my json of `ð??¸`.  I was using the fetch in React Native to make a request, and the JSON parsing would result in this error until I took the Emoji out of the JSON. For more: ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177808/emoji-characters-cannot-be-encoded-to-json

Comment: For browser Chrome is Uncaught SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6

Answer (score 14):

As @Seth Holladay @MinusFour commented, you are parsing an `undefined` variable.
Try adding an `if` condition before doing the parse.

`if (typeof test1 !== 'undefined') {
  test2 = JSON.parse(test1);
}`

Note: This is just a check for `undefined` case. Any other parsing issues still need to be handled.

Comment: True, this would prevent the program from crashing. However, in most cases, it's good for a program to crash when given invalid input. Depends on where the data is coming from, though. Either way, note that lots of things are invalid JSON, not just `undefined`, so this is hardly a robust check. https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/03/03/the-art-of-throwing-javascript-errors/

Comment: True. This just covers the `Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` and other issues still need to be handled. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
localStorage.clear()
```

That'll clear the stored data. Then refresh and things should start to work.

Answer (score 4):

Your app is attempting to parse the undefined JSON web token. Such malfunction may occur due to the wrong usage of the local storage. Try to clear your local storage.

Example for Google Chrome:

1. F12
2. Application
3. Local Storage
4. Clear All

Comment: I just had this issue and [Alexander Borisov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13871107/alexander-borisov) is spot on. Please allow me to add "Session Storage" to the list of places to clear. In my case, I am using this to store auth tokens and the issue came about during a transition from Flask to FastAPI.

Answer (score 2):

For me, that happened because I had an empty component in my page -

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
   {
   ".page.messages": {
       "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": []        
      }
   }
```

Deleting this piece of code resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` then you could do the following quick checks:

```
jsObj = JSON.parse(data)
```

1. data - check the data is **undefined** or not
2. data - check the data is a valid  **JSON string** or not
3. data - check the data is corrupted by unwanted whitespace or not

   ```
   data = data.trim(); // remove the unwanted whitespace
   jsObj = JSON.parse(data);
   ```
4. data - check the received data uses the correct encoding format('**utf8', 'utf16le', 'ucs2'**) or not

   ```
   fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, data) { ... });

   fs.readFile(file, 'utf16le', function(err, data) { ... }); // le - little endian

   fs.readFile(file, 'ucs2', function(err, data) { ... });   // kind  of 'utf16le'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the interfering `messages` that come on to the page. There are multiple frames on the page which communicate with the page using window message event and object. few of them can be third party services like `cookieq` for managing cookies, or may be `cartwire` an e-com integration service.

You need to handle the onmessage event to check from where the messages are coming, and then parse the JSON accordingly.

I faced a similar problem, where one of the integration was passing a JSON object and other was passing a string starting with `u`

Answer (score 0):

you can simply check data has some value or undefined :

```
if(res){
 let apiResponse = JSON.parse(res);
}
```

it will work.

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue for 2 days, let me show you how I fixed it.

This was how the code looked when I was getting the error:

```
request.onload = function() {
    // This is where we begin accessing the Json
    let data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    console.log(data)
}
```

This is what I changed to get the result I wanted:

```
request.onload = function() {
    // This is where we begin accessing the Json
    let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(data)
}
```

So all I really did was change 
    `this.response` to `this.responseText`.