# How to use ES6 template literal in defining sessionStorage key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, string-interpolation, sessionstorage, template-literals

I am trying to use ES6 template literal syntax to set sessionStorage where part of the key is the active tab id.

I attempted first to put the ES6 template literal within the method:

```
sessionStorage.getItem(`tabContent + ${this.props.activeTabKey}`)
```

But this wouldn't compile.

I next created a constant within my method and then referred to it within the sessionStorage method:

```
//attempt 1
const activeTabSessionStorageName = `tabContent + ${this.props.activeTabKey}`
(sessionStorage.getItem(`${activeTabSessionStorageName}`))

// attempt 2

const activeTabSessionStorageName = `tabContent + ${this.props.activeTabKey}`

  sessionStorage.getItem(JSON.stringify(activeTabSessionStorageName))

//attempt 3
const activeTabSessionStorageName = `tabContent + ${this.props.activeTabKey}`
(sessionStorage.getItem(this.activeTabSessionStorageName))
```

I am not sure what would be the correct syntax but both failed and came up with the error:

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

My goal is to have a way to dynamically check the storage to see if they key exists and then set it if not.

I am not that familiar with sessionStorage other than high level understanding. I know the key and the value have to be strings.

I am using React and Redux

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with the very first thing you posted: `sessionStorage.getItem(\`tabContent + ${this.props.activeTabKey}\`)`. So let's go back to that. When you say `it wouldn't compile` what error message did you get?

Comment: Note if you are meaning to concatenate `tabContent` to whatever `activeTabKey` is you do not need the concatenation (`+`) operator just have it as `tabContent${this.props.activeTabKey}`

Comment: @PatrickEvans - that's true, but it's neither here nor there in solving the problem and probably only serves to confuse the OP. The string `tabContent + someIdentifier` is just as valid as `tabContentsomeIdentifier`

Comment: @Adam, didn't say it would solve the problem, hence why i preceded the statement with _"Note"_

Comment: I get an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 @Adam

Comment: code for error: 
 if (sessionStorage.getItem(JSON.stringify(`tabContent + ${this.props.activeTabKey}`))){
tabItems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(JSON.stringify(`tabContent + ${this.props.activeTabKey}`)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your error is likely a result of attempting to `JSON.parse()` an `undefined` value.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613243/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-in-json-at-position-0)

[`window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) can be combined with [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to commit data for sessions.

See below for a practical example, including [`Template Literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and a safe escape for cases when no `sessionStorage` `Item` is found.

```
// Hypothetical Object.
const hypotheticalObject = {
  id: 'unique id',
  data: 'data ..'
}

// Set Object to Session Storage.
window.sessionStorage.setItem(`CONTENT + ${hypotheticalObject.id}`, JSON.stringify(hypotheticalObject))

// Get Object.
const retrievedObject = window.sessionStorage.getItem(`CONTENT + ${hypotheticalObject.id}`) && JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem(`CONTENT + ${hypotheticalObject.id}`)) || false

// Log.
console.log(retrievedObject)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was unsure of the syntax of my statement so I wasn't sure if it was an issue with that or with the value. I need to re-order the rendering so the value isn't undefined when the component mounts. Thank you!