# Showing SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0 issues in capacitor project when try to build

Tags: ionic4, capacitor

SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0

at JSON.parse ()
at Integration.getCapacitorCLIConfig.lodash.memoize
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli/lib/integrations/capacitor/index.js:33:25)

Comment: From this error, I can understand that you are attempting to parse undefined, which is not valid JSON. Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613243/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-in-json-at-position-0

Comment: Make sure your global and project version of CLIs match.

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same problem.
I was able to solve it by upgrading the project version of capacitor.

The previous versions of the capacitor `capacitor/cli` and `capacitor/core` were 1.4.0, I was able to solve it by upgrading them (and `capacitor/android` and `capacitor/ios`) to:

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.5",
    "@capacitor/core": "^2.4.5",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^2.4.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
   ...
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.5"
}
```

Maybe you should upgrade your global `ionic/cli` version too, mine is 6.16.1.

After upgrading the versions on the project, the capacitor commands worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade capacitor last version
npm install @capacitor/cli@latest @capacitor/core@latest

Answer (score 0):

Tried upgrading my ionic/cli, capacitor version to the latest but after a circus of missing dependencies I uninstalled ionic/cli and installed a previous stable version 6.11.0 and worked perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using ionic `v6` with capacitor/cli and capacitor/core `v2.4.0`. Downgrading the ionic cli to `v5` fixed it for me.

```
npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli

npm install -g ionic@5
```