# I am unable to integrate the paymetric iframe, payment gateway. I am facing an error "json unexpected token u at position 0"

Tags: angular, iframe, payment-gateway, spartacus-storefront, worldpay

I am currently trying to integrate the Paymetric, Payment gateway using the iframes as mentioned in their document. However when I try to integrate it, after getting the URL to be rendered in their iframe. I am getting the below error "JSON unexpected token u at position 0".
Has someone faced a similar issue, can someone help me here, please?
I am trying to integrate this with Angular.

I got to know in my initial research that this comes as it is trying to parse a JSON which is undefined. I also observed that this URL when we hit in the browser directly renders the iframe content , but not within the Iframe.

Anyone who has integrated worldpay/paymetric payment gateway with Angular framework in I frame mode. Any help or leads would be much appreciated,

Please do let me know if any further inputs are needed to provide the help.

Comment: Any further inputs are needed on this please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613243/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-in-json-at-position-0)

Comment: Please do a search on the error text as your first recourse. A search came up with the answer above as the first result.

Comment: I did try, but  the data what it is trying to refer is not in our hand . There is a plugin provided which i added in the index.html which has to inject the necessary data into the iframe as far as I understand but it does not seem to do so